# How to acces data from a database and return it as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, sqlite

I'm new to **Javascript** and I have to solve a task for my Homework.
I have to get specific data (album titles and the album IDs) from a Database in one class, return this Data to another class and format it with template literals there.

```
getAlbums: function (db) {
    sql = `SELECT DISTINCT Title, AlbumId FROM albums`;
    let title = [], id = [];
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        rows.forEach((row)=>{
            title.push(row.Title);
            id.push(row.AlbumId);
        });
    });
    return [title, id];
}
```

this is the function where I get the data from the database. When I put a `console.log(title)` inside the `db.all` function, the titles array is filled correctly. But it does not return this array to the other class, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

If I put a `console.log(title)` outside the `db.all` function, it returns an empty array and I don't get an error. The output is just `undefined`.

**The method call in my other class:**

```
showAlbum: function (db) {
    let albumID = model.getAlbums(db);
    //let album = "";
    //let albId = "";

    albumID.forEach((element) => {
        //album = element.title;
        //albId = element.id;
        console.log(`Albumtitle: ${element.title} AlbumID: ${element.id}\n`);
    });
}
```

How can I transfer the arrays correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JS code to the following.

```
getAlbums: function (data) {
sql = `SELECT DISTINCT Title, AlbumId FROM albums`;
let title = [], id = [];
data.data.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    rows.forEach((row)=>{
        title.push(row.Title);
        id.push(row.AlbumId);
    });
});
return [title, id];
}
```

then

```
showAlbum: function (data) {
let albumID = model.getAlbums(data.data);
//let album = "";
//let albId = "";

albumID.forEach((element) => {
    //album = element.title;
    //albId = element.id;
    console.log(`Albumtitle: ${element.title} AlbumID: ${element.id}\n`);
});
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I now get the following Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Comment: Change your `db.all` to `data.db.all` and check if it's working?

Comment: Wherever you are using your `db` argument, try changing it to `data.db`

Comment: Still the same, but now it is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined"

Comment: Please check the edited comment with update. Lemme know if it works.

Comment: whoops, I misread tha "data.data". Changed that, but I get the sane TypeError, instead of "db" its "data" now. It throws the error after `data.data.all`